# PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied on windows (pyinstaller)

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, pyinstaller

I am creating an application in python (3.4) with tkinter and I am compiling it with pyinstaller. The code fragment that brings the error is this:

```
client = paramiko.SSHClient()
known_hosts = open(self.resource_path("known_hosts")) # Linea 73
client.load_host_keys(known_hosts)
```

The error is thrown when I click on a button that executes that part of the code, that is, the application runs rather well. The error is this:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tkinter\__init__.py", line 1538, in __call__
  File "prueba.py", line 73, in aceptar
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\Users\\Hernan\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\_MEI124282\\known_hosts'
```

I clarify that I am compiling it and running in windows 10.

I tried to execute the exe as administrator but still giving the same error. I verified the path of the file and it exists, so I discard that the file does not exist. I also tried to compile the exe in a cmd with administrator permissions, but it did not give me a solution either.

Any ideas ?

PD: add code...

```
    def resource_path(self, relative_path):
        """ Get absolute path to resource, works for dev and for PyInstaller """
        base_path = getattr(sys, '_MEIPASS',     os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
        return os.path.join(base_path, relative_path)
```

Comment: Have you tried to rune the program as admin. Right click the exe and select run as admin. This may help or they may be an issue with your file path in the code.

Comment: Yes, i tried and not work. i edit the post with the "resource_path".

Comment: Try to delete the directory `C:\\Users\\Hernan\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\_MEI124282\\known_hosts` and try gain.

Comment: The folder _MEIXXXXXX is generated randomly